# How to use gon with Jasminerice in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jasmine

QUESTION
I'm on Rails 3.2, and am using gems 'gon' and 'jasminerice'.  How do I mimic controller code where I setup the gon data, and how do I ensure that this gon data is available to my javascript files when testing via jasminerice?

ANSWER
I actually came up with the solution myself, and am simply posting here in order to save somebody time and frustration.  The first step is to create a 'helper method' (i.e., SpecHelper module, see https://github.com/bradphelan/jasminerice) which sets up the gon variable in a way that mimics the controller code; let's call it 'helper1'.  The second step is to create a fixture (make sure to load it in your spec via 'loadFixtures') that has a header as follows:

```
<head>
  <% helper1() %>
  <%= include_gon() %>
</head>
```

The key is to put the call to the helper method **before** the 'include_gon' line.

Comment: i'm not sure how this works... because a fixture file is an `.html` file, not a `.html.erb` file, so how does it actually interpolate something like `<%= include_gon %>`?

Answer (score -1):

If you need to concern Rails controller in Jasmine, that's wrong.

Jasmin is for Javascript unit test. Dependencies in unit test should be reduced to minimum. Mixing server logic in front-end unit test is a big NO.

A better approach would be using fixture or factory to supply the data/context needed.

If you need to test integration, use Capybara, which also don't need such hack.

Comment: A fixture is in fact being used (second step).  All I meant by 'controller code' was in regards to prepping gon.